# Maven submodule does not exist in Jenkins

Tags: linux, maven, jenkins, centos

i cant do any maven commande and this is the error :

```
Child module /root/.jenkins/workspace/testmaven/trunk/Sermicro of /root/.jenkins/workspace/testmaven/trunk/pom.xml does not exist
```

im using mvn version : Apache Maven 3.0.5

```
The project fr:trunk:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (/root/.jenkins/workspace/testmaven/trunk/pom.xml) has 1 error [ERROR] Child module /root/.jenkins/workspace/testmaven/trunk/Sermicro of /root/.jenkins/workspace/testmaven/trunk/pom.xml does not exist
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. How does your `pom.xml` look like, what command are you executing etc.

Comment: mvn clean and my pom is  :

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>fr</groupId>
  <artifactId>trunk</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
   <module>A</module>
   <module>core</module>
   <module>B</module>
   <module>C</module>
  </modules>

Comment: can we speak with skype if u want

Comment: sorry, given the details I can't help you with that. Maybe you should read a bit about more maven. Probably, this is also not related to Jenkins, is it?

Comment: thank you but i dont need to read more about maven bcoz my project running normaly  when i enter into project A or B and i execute the mvn clean the probleme is  when i running the mother pom they dont work they tell me project B does not exist.